# translating between measurement based and circuit based quantum computation

Tags: measurement, error-correction, quantum-circuit, stabilizer-code

I think I understand circuit based QC (CBQC) well enough; I know very little about MBQC. From what I read it seems that they are somehow "equivalent". I'd like to check this with a concrete example from QECC. I can find circuits to encode/decode a stabilizer code; we can take the perfect $[[5,1,3]]$ code as an example https://www.cgranade.com/python-quaec/. How would I translate these circuits to MBQC counterparts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalence is derived from the fact that you can:

0. Take a big amount of qubits, and perform CZ between every 2 neighbors (entangle them). This big entangled by CZ resource is called "Cluster State". [There are many cases that this CZ is not deterministic, so only some of them succeed, so you finish with a smaller cluster state, but it is ok as long as the probability of success is big enough, and your starting amount is big enough].
1. Each 1 Qubit general unitary rotation gate is implemented with measurement in Z rotated base (or H followed by Z rotation followed by Z measurement which is equivalent:
   [image]

[image]

equivalent to [image]

you just need to correct with X depend on the outcome of measumrent

2. Each 2 Qubit gate is implemented using $CZ$ gate which was prepared before you started your algorithm.

**Now**, the way the whole thing is working, is that once you have a big cluster state, your measurements (1Q gates) are pushing the state toward the measure direction of the graph, and you can finish the algorithm, by just measuring the endpoints of this graph.

See the following example:

[image]

[**Good resource to learn it**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.4193.pdf)